# Jquery Video player Auto play issue in android mobile and iphone

Tags: php, jquery, html5-video, video.js

I am using jquery video.js. I have issue in autoplay video for android mobile and iphone devices.

It is working fine in my computer browser

My code is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script href="skin/frontend/fashfolies/default/js/video-js/video.js"></script><!-- skin/frontend/fashfolies/default/js -->
        <link src="skin/frontend/fashfolies/default/css/video-js/video-js.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>
        <video id='my-video1' class='video-js' controls  style='width:50%; height:300px;' data-setup='{}' muted>
            <source src='media/home-video/brand.mp4' type='video/mp4'>            
                <p class='vjs-no-js'>To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that<a href='#' target='_blank'>supports HTML5 video</a>
                </p>
            </source>
        </video>
        <script>
            var vi=document.getElementById("my-video1");


            //vi.autoplay=true;
            setIntervel(function(){
                vi.autoplay=true;
                vi.load();  
            },2000);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in particular video.js but i think the point is that mobile OS intentionally disable autoplay on mobile devices in order to protect user’s bandwidth. The trick you could try is to set video play on an user fired event, for example:

```
 $(window).on("touchstart", function() 
 { 
   vi.play();  
 }
```

Comment: It should be work after a tap or scrolling the document, if you used same event in my example. Did you get errors?

Comment: not any errors its not auto play video for mobile devices

Comment: I can't understand why, maybe it's for video.js. So consider what i told about mobile OS block and the use of an user fired event in the video.js library context

Comment: any solution for this question??